# Does having many modules in an Excel file run slower than having many subs in one module?

Tags: performance, vba, excel

Will having many modules inside your Excel workbook run slower than combining your subs inside one module?

It's more of an organizational thing for me as I like to have different modules named for different functions they perform. But I was just curious if one way or another makes your code run slower.

Any info on this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: BTW this question belongs to www.superuser.com :)

Comment: + 1 though a good question but asked in the wrong place :)

Comment: sorry! Thought this might be the spot to ask.

Comment: @SiddharthRout being on topic there doesn't make it off topic here. It's a valid programming question I believe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tested it with 10 modules with 50 procedures in each module. There was no difference.

[image]

I guess it finally may depend on the number of modules and the number of procedures.

It may be slow with 1000 modules with 1000 procedures in each module. I can't say for sure because I have not tested it.

In short, I guess you are safe with creating separate modules like you are doing because you may never reach that limit :)

**Edit**

Tested it with 30 modules with 100 procedures in each module. There was no difference.